# blueimp jquery file upload - rename filename with data input like title

Tags: php, mysql, blueimp, image-upload

I would like to rename the filename with a hidden additional form field followed by a small unique random number while uploading the photo. The file name should look like this: hidden_form_field-random_number.jpg = hello_Dj84lx.jpg

I have found solutions to do random names and so on but not with an inserted form. I have tried to use $file->title from the examples but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem.

First of I added this function to the upload/server/php/index.php file

```
protected function generate_unique_filename($filename = ""){
        $extension = "";
        if ( $filename != "" ){
            $extension = pathinfo($filename , PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if ( $extension != "" ){
                $extension = "." . $extension;
            }
        }           
        $characters = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
        $randomString = "";
        for ($i = 0; $i < 5 ; $i++) {
            $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
        }
        return $filename.'_'.date('siHdmy').$randomString.$extension;
}
```

Then I edited the UploadHandler.php file. I added a public variable $mytitle and replaced this code:

```
$file->name = $this->get_file_name($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error, $index, $content_range);
```

with this

```
$this->mytitle='what-ever-text-filled-in-the-title-form-field';
$file->name = $this->generate_unique_filename($this->mytitle);
```

Comment: There might be a cleaner solution but it worked out for me. ;)